# How to have a Label surrounded by two select boxes in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking to have the following html render a select box, then a label, then another select box all in one row while using twitter bootstrap 2.0  What css could I add to bootstrap to accomplish this?

```
<div class="row">
    <select class="span4"></select>
    <label class="span4">UCA</label>
    <select class="span4"></select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ultimately decided on this

```
<div class="row-fluid form-inline">
    <select class="span4"></select>
    <div class="span4 pagination-centered">@displayTag</div>
    <select class="span4"></select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at using the pull-left or pull-right classes.

```
<div class="row">
    <select class="span4 pull-left"></select>
    <label class="span4 pull-left">UCA</label>
    <select class="span4 pull-left"></select>
</div>
```